# Turning a Rust `String` formatted exactly like an Array into an `Array`

Tags: arrays, string, rust, type-conversion

I am working on a small, simple interpreter for a language i'm working on and i'm using Rust.

I have managed to lex the file into a list:

`{function1 ("args", "args", "args!")}` into `"["fn","function1",["args","args","args!"]]"` works, for example (but it's a string because find+replace was used).

`"["fn","function1",["args","args","args!"]]"` (a string) into `["fn","function1",["args","args","args!"]]` (an array) is impossible with my current skillset, which is why i've came here.

However, now that i have the `String`, i am stuck finding a way to parse the string into an array, which would be a lot more useful.

I have tried searching up terms such as "how to turn rust string formatted exactly like an array into an array" or "turn string with array inside it to array rust" to no relevant results.

I have tried contorting impl into various forms.

```
let array = string.impl(From <String>)
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking for. Could you provide an example input and output (and a type signature if possible). Are you looking to parse the string `"["a", "b", "c", ...]` into an array?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i want.

Comment: That's not a string that looks like an array though, arrays can only hold one kind of data, but here `"function1",[...` you have both a string (`"function1"`) and another array (`[...`) which are different datatypes.
You should probably take a good look at the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) or ask a tutor/teacher (or hire one) because as it is you're just typing in random concatenated words and that's not getting you anywhere.

Comment: What you want to do is impossible if @cameron1024 interpreted your intent correctly. Array sizes must be known at compile time, while an arbitrary's `String` length might not be known during compile time. Hence you may only deserialize such a string into a `Vec`, but not an array.